# List Found Folders in File Dialog

Tags: c#, search, directory, explorer

im trying to get a FileDialog, where are shown searches folders.
For example: 
Im searching in a directory "x/123/abc" for all folders who have "ab" in it.
All found Folders should ne shown in a dialog like "FileDialog", so that the Search-results are clickable (the folders can be opened).

I just found ways to get those results in an array, but not in such an "Explorer-Window".
The searching works, at this point I get all Directories in Messageboxes:

```
string tbKDI;
            tbKDI = Convert.ToString("*"+tbKDIsearch.Text+"*");
            string KDIfolder = @"\\SERVER\\Service\\02_Kunden_SW_und_Daten";

                foreach (string KDIfolderResult in System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(KDIfolder, tbKDI))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(KDIfolderResult.ToString());

                }
```

But how do I het them in such an "Explorer-Window"?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure what type of project your building, but you should have a control for that.

Comment: It´s an WPF-Application. A User searches for example, a client-name (ex: "gut"), or client-ID. Folders in that directory are named like: ClientID_ClientName. And all those folders which have "gut" in its names should be listet in a kind of explorer-window. And the wanted folder could then be chosen and opened.